# Como alterar o idioma de erro de validação no HTML5?

Tags: html, html5, validação

Há alguma forma de alterar o idioma do erro de validação de **minLength**?
Obs: quando tento dar submit em um campo **"required"** vazio, aparece a mensagem `Preenche este campo!` em português. Somente o erro de validação do **minLength** está em inglês.

[image: Erro de validação em inglês]

Comment: Vide [MDN Form data validation - Customized error messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Customized_error_messages): "*They depend on the browser locale, which means that you can have a page in one language but an error message displayed in another language.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito provavelmente isso é pq o seu OS ou o seu Browser está em Inglês, teste em outra maquina, que esteja com idioma local Pt que deve aparecer a msg em português.

Tirando isso vc pode tentar forçar uma mudança de idioma no cabeçalho HTTP do documento, ou declarando a `lang` na tag `html` ou com a meta `http-equiv` no `content` dela.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"><!-- recomendado pela W3C -->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt-br"><!-- não recomendado pela W3C -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

A [Mozilla não faz ressalvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Utilizando_meta_tags#Content-language) quanto a `meta http-equiv`, já [a W3C não recomenda](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-http-and-lang#meta_summary).

A W3C recomenda que vc declare direto no cabeçalho HTTP o `Content-Language: pt-br` ou na tag `html`

> Esse uso do `content-language` valor de um `http-equiv` atributo é reprovado pela especificação HTML e não deve mais ser usado. Em vez disso, você deve sempre usar um `lang` atributo na `html` tag para declarar o idioma padrão do texto na página.