# Bootstrap DateTimePicker Moment.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datapicker

Estou tentando implementar o Bootstrap DateTimePicker no meu projeto que está com a versão 4.3.1 do Bootstrap.

O problema é que eu não sei como se faz isso.
Eu baixei deste site:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Date-Time-Picker-Bootstrap-4.html

e ele me trouxe esta estrutura de arquivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei incluí-los no meu projeto assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/Date-Time-Picker-Bootstrap-4/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
```

e coloquei o input assim:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="data1">
```

enquanto no jQuery coloquei assim:

```
$("#data1").datetimepicker();
```

E não aconteceu nada. Apenas um erro no console, dizendo que nao reconheceu o comando `.datetimepicker()`. Alguém me da uma ajuda por favor?

Erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument.

Também me mostra um erro sobre o `moment.js`, como eu consigo baixar ele manualmente para implementá-lo?

**EDIT:**

Eu consegui resolver o erro, colocando o moment desta forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Porém, eu nao posso utilizar ele atraves deste link. Como eu baixo ele manualmente para adicionar o caminho ao meu projeto?

**EDIT1:** Como eu mudo a linguagem para português?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reapre que os dias e os meses então em inglês. Como eu os mudo para português?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tradução pelo browser ^

Comment: Sobre a data vi isso hj https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs as vezes te interessa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que faltou vc indexar o moment.js antes do JS datapicker

Vc pode baixa-lo aqui: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Date-Time-Picker-Bootstrap-4/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js (basta dar um ctrl+C no script e colocar em um arquivo .js no seu ambiente de trabalho e indexar no seu documento)

Veja um exemplo funcionando no Bootstrap 4 abaixo, repare na ordem e nos arquivos que foram indexados no documento

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Date-Time-Picker-Bootstrap-4/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<style>
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <h4>Date/Time Picker Component For Bootstrap 4 Demo</h4>
          <div class="row">
              <div class='col-sm-6'>
                  <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' />
              </div>
      
          </div>
      </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Date-Time-Picker-Bootstrap-4/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: E como vou baixá-lo? Apenas copiar o conteudo do link e colocar dentro de um arquivo no meu projeto e encaminhar a ele?

Comment: @edro isso mesmo rss, tão fácil quanto parece. Basta copiar o script do link e salvar como meudatapicker.js e indexar no seu documento, lembrando de seguir a ordem de indexação dos scripts, ele deve vir após o jQuery etc, consulte a ordem na resposta acima

Comment: hmm, entendi. Mas acho que vc me passou o link errado. Eu tentei copiar o script do seu link e não funcionou. Mas com este link https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js funcionou perfeitamente. Colocando na ordem que vc falou. Obrigado

Comment: @edro a ideia é a mesma, copiar o conteúdo do arquivo .js da fonte. Estranho que aqui funcionou com o link que citei... não sei dizer pq. Mas vc já pegou a maldade, é isso ai, que bom que deu certo, []´s

Comment: Hugo, só mais uma questão, que nao estou conseguindo encontrar. Como eu consigo mudar a lingua do datepicker para portugues? Pois eu reparei que, por exemplo o mês, aparece em inglês, como "July". Encontrei em um lugar dizendo para colocar `language: pt`, nas propriedades quando vou colocar a função no jquery, mas não funcionou. Apareceu o erro: Uncaught TypeError: option language is not recognized!

Sabe como eu posso fazer?

Comment: Cheguei a tentar também `locale: 'pt-br'` e também não funcionou.

Comment: @edro parece que é um pouco mais complicado do que parece isso... Vc pode tentar forçar o idioma da página pra ver se ele muda o formato, aqui tem umas dicas. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/394862/como-alterar-o-idioma-de-erro-de-valida%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-html5/394865#394865 mas provavelmente não vai dar certo nesse caso. Além disso, li no link do Datapicker isso "`ate format. See moment.js' docs for valid formats.
005
format: false,
006
 
007
// Changes the heading of the datepicker when in "days" view.
008
dayViewHeaderFormat: 'MMMM YYYY',
`" continua... \/

Comment: Ou seja vc tem que olhar nos Docs do Moment.js para ver como muda o formato da data. Veja mais nesse link https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/ e em último caso abra uma nova pergunta pedindo ajuda nesse ponto e coloque o que vc tiver de código links e detalhes JS não é muito minha praia, mas as vezes alguém aqui já passou por isso e pode te ajuda melhor do que eu

Comment: Hugo, o formato da data está de acordo com o nosso padrão brasileiro. Apenas os meses, como por exemplo "Julho" está "July", no titulo. Vou deixar um print na pergunta.

Comment: Olha aqui https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/ o seu Windows está em ingles ou o browser? E como te sugeri, o melhor é abrir uma nova pergunta para alguem te ajudar com a tradução, pois ela não tem a ver com a pergunta inicial feita, e seria ideal abrir uma nova pergunta...

Comment: Creio que os dois kskssks, mas traduzido pelo browser fica completamente errado. Outro print na pergunta

Comment: @edro abra uma nova pergunta, vai facilitar para vc ter uma resposta sobre essa assunto em específico, já que ele não é o foco da pergunta original

Comment: ok, obrigado pela ajuda.